# React-Native rendering multiple images

Tags: javascript, android, ios, arrays, react-native

I am trying to render multiple images from marvels api.

Here is a example:

```
 "images": [
          {
            "path": "http://i.annihil.us/u/prod/marvel/i/mg/e/00/52264475c3499",
            "extension": "jpg"
          },
          {
            "path": "http://i.annihil.us/u/prod/marvel/i/mg/e/70/51fc0cb22a1ff",
            "extension": "jpg"
          },
          {
            "path": "http://i.annihil.us/u/prod/marvel/i/mg/f/70/51fc0c8f4dee4",
            "extension": "jpg"
          },
          {
            "path": "http://i.annihil.us/u/prod/marvel/i/mg/7/40/51f9695a3ee93",
            "extension": "jpg"
          } ...
```

And here is the some of the code:

```
class Character extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    let comic  = this.props.character;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{comic.description}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.castTitle}>Characters in this comic:</Text>
        <View>
          {comic.characters.items.map(items =>
            <Text key={items.name} style={styles.castActor}>
              &bull; {items.name}
            </Text>
          )}
        </View>
        <View>
        <View>
          {comic.images.map(images =>
          <ListView  key={images.path}>
            <Image source={{uri: images.path }} style={styles.Images} />
          </ListView>
          )}

        </View>

        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

I have tried a lot of things, and if i wrap it in ListView i get the Error:

```
Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'dataSource.rowIdentities')
```

I don't know why, is there maybe a special method of rendering multiple images?

Regards Anker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hej fætter! ;)

I think your problem is, that you aren't using the ListView the right way. Have a look at the docs on the react-native website:
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#listview

You probably want to do something like:

```
constructor(props) {
  const imgsrc = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (img1, img2) => img1.path !== img2.path })
  this.state = {
    imageSource: imgsrc.cloneWithRows(props.comic.images)
  }
}
... // In render function
<View>
  <ListView
    dataSource={this.state.imageSource}
    renderRow={image => <Image source={{uri: image.path}} style={styles.Images} />}
  />
</View>
...
```

This may look at bit strange when coming from a background in webdevelopment, but it's necessary to make the scroll-experience smooth.

See you!
Anders