# React-Native Dynamic Image Source?

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I'm trying to gather image sources from a JSON file but whenever I use a JSON objects source I get a module error. Is there any workaround for this?

JSON FILE:

```
 {
   "Image": {"source": "./SourceFolder/ImageFile.png"}
 }
```

JS FILE

```
 const file = require('./jason.json');
 var jason = JSON.stringify(file.Image);
 jason = JSON.parse(jason);

 <Image source={require(jason.source)} />
```

Comment: check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44468500/image-react-native-not-working

Comment: @JigarShah thanks but that didn't work either. I think I'm stuck here. There may not be a way to store a bunch of image sources from a json and use them accordingly.

Comment: try like this,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36375532/react-native-rendering-multiple-images

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic requires are not supported unfortunalty. You need to pre-require all of your images, then you're able to dynamically call them from a reference.

```
const images = {
  image1: require('some_file.png'),
}

<Image source={images["image1"]} />
```

Comment: Thats a bummer. I'm using multiple Image files. Do I need to require each one directly? Or if I have a folder of images could I just pre-require the folder?

Comment: And even if I pre-require it, I cant use it from the JSON

Comment: I don't think you can pre-require directories or images like that, as it all needs to be pre-bundled. You're best trying to host them somewhere (like a Google storage bucket for cheap) and do a dynamic require with the image source.

Comment: thanks, I just saved my data in a local js file in an array. Probably a terrible idea but if I ever put the app on the market I'll try your idea. Thanks